# How to store value in cypress/javascript so can use to assert against later?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am new to cypress and I just need a little bit of syntax help. My intellisense is not working so I am not sure if this is the correct command. Basically I want to grab the text of an element and store it as a variable. Later on when I perform an assertion against a new element, I want to assert the new element contains the same text from the previous element.

Is this the correct way to store the text of an element? I don't really understand .wrap even after reading it. Belwo I am trying to get the first element (elementExample() is a method performs a cy.get of a element value).

```
 elementExample().index(1).wrap().as('element1');
```

If somebody can show me an example to store the element and to assert against it, be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to save the innerText, you can do something like this:

```js
cy.get("selector").invoke("text").as("element1")

cy.get("@element1").then((element1) => {
  cy.get("selectorelement2")
    .invoke("text")
    .then((element2) => {
      expect(element1).to.equal(element2)
    })
})
```

You can also separately save the inner text and then later assert as well. Something like this:

```js
cy.get("selector").eq(1).invoke("text").as("element1")
//Do something
cy.get("selector").invoke("text").as("element2")
//Do something
cy.get("@element1").then((element1) => {
  cy.get("@element2").then((element2) => {
    expect(element1).to.equal(element2)
  })
})
```

Assuming `elementExample()` translates into `cy.get("selector")` then the above code should look like:

```js
elementExample().eq(1).invoke("text").as("element1")
//Do something
elementExample().invoke("text").as("element2")
//Do something
cy.get("@element1").then((element1) => {
  cy.get("@element2").then((element2) => {
    expect(element1).to.equal(element2)
  })
})
```

`.eq()` will get the DOM element at a specific index in an array of elements. `.eq(1)` will get the second element. For accessing the first element we have to use `eq(0)`.

Comment: How can we invoke an attribute value?

Comment: You can do like this `cy.get('selector').invoke('attr','attr-name')`